# Determine if a substructure is present in a chemical structure using SMILES string (substructure fingerprint)

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

A [SMILES (Simplified molecular-input line-entry system) string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) is a string that represents a chemical structure using ASCII characters. For example, water (\$H_2O\$) can be written in SMILES as `H-O-H`.

However, for simplicity, the single bonds (`-`) and hydrogen atoms (`H`) are frequently omitted. Thus, a molecules with only single bonds like *n*-pentane (\$CH_3CH_2CH_2CH_2CH_3\$) can be represented as simply `CCCCC`, and ethanol (\$CH_3CH_2OH\$) as `CCO` or `OCC` (which atom you start from does not matter).

n-pentane:[image: n-pentane]

ethanol:[image: ethanol]

In SMILES, double bonds are represented with `=` and triple bonds with `#`. So ethene:

[image: ethene]

can be represented as `C=C`, and hydrogen cyanide:

[image: HCN]

can be represented as `C#N` or `N#C`.

SMILES uses parentheses when representing branching:

[image: HCN]

Bromochlorodifluoromethane can be represented as `FC(Br)(Cl)F`, `BrC(F)(F)Cl`, `C(F)(Cl)(F)Br`, etc.

For rings, atoms that close rings are numbered:

[image: cyclohexane]

First strip the `H` and start from any `C`. Going round the ring, we get `CCCCCC`. Since the first and last `C` are bonded, we write `C1CCCCC1`.

Use this tool: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit3/index.html to try drawing your own structures and convert them to SMILES, or vice versa.

**Task**

Your program shall receive two SMILES string. The first one is a molecule, the second is a substructure (portion of a molecule). The program should return `true` if the substructure is found in the molecule and `false` if not. For simplicity, only above explanation of SMILES will be used (no need to consider stereochemistry like cis-trans, or aromaticity) and the only atoms will be:

- `O`
- `C`
- `N`
- `F`

Also, the substructure do not contain `H`.

**Examples**

```
CCCC C
true

CCCC CC
true

CCCC F
false

C1CCCCC1 CC
true

C1CCCCC1 C=C
false

COC(C1)CCCC1C#N C(C)(C)C // substructure is a C connected to 3 other Cs
true

COC(C1)CCCCC1#N COC1CC(CCC1)C#N // SMILES strings representing the same molecule
true

OC(CC1)CCC1CC(N)C(O)=O CCCCO
true

OC(CC1)CCC1CC(N)C(O)=O NCCO
true

OC(CC1)CCC1CC(N)C(O)=O COC
false
```

Shortest code wins. Refrain from using external libraries.

Comment: Could you add a few more complexer test cases like the last one? The first five test cases can be solved using a single `contains` builtin.

Comment: As for that last test case, the `COC(C1)CCCC1C#N` can't be pasted to the tool you've linked (it automatically changes to `COC1CC(CCC1)C#N`..) Also, would `COC(C1)CCCCC1#N` with `CCCCCC` result in truthy, since it does contain a substructure of six subsequence `C`-atoms (the entire circle `(C1)CCCCC1`, and the additional branch to a `C` in `COC`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen i will add more examples. The tool converts the SMILES string to a canonical SMILES string (it uses a standard algorithm that ensures a unique output).

`COC(C1)CCCCC1#N` with `CCCCCC` will be truthy.
`COC(C1)CCCCC1#N` with `COC1CC(CCC1)C#N` will be truthy.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 31 bytes

```
MoleculeContainsQ@@Molecule/@#&
```

Takes input as a list of 2 strings (the source and the pattern molecules).

As you could guess, this checks if the first molecule (parsed via `Molecule`) contains the second one by using the `MoleculeContainsQ` function.

This doesn't seem to work in the online interpreter on TIO; I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. It works on my local machine, though. Of course, this is not using an external library: it's completely built-in functionality!

Comment: i'm looking for answers that do some parsing, but as your answer uses built-in functionality, i guess you've found a loophole! +1